# Python 3.5 Typing ABCMeta does not define '__getitem__'

Tags: python, pycharm, typing

I am trying out Python 3.5's typing module by marking up a few of my functions.

I have a function that returns a list though I am getting a warning in PyCharm.

The warning reads:

> Class 'ABCMeta' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances

```
from typing import List

def get_list() -> List[int]:
    return [1, 2, 3]
```

Is anyone able to better interpret that message then I can?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of PyCharm?

Comment: 5.0.2. I think it's the EAP build

Comment: Seems very likely that you're not actually using Python3.5 here, even if it appears that you are. Pycharm might be doing something under the hood

Comment: Oh wait, I think I misread. This is a *warning* from PyCharm, not an error from Python when it's being run? PyCharm is just wrong then, ignore it.

Comment: Which is strange, because [this blog post](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/11/python-3-5-type-hinting-in-pycharm-5/) says that it should be working

Comment: Cannot replicate using pycharm and python 3.4, the fact you are using an `EAP` may be relevant

Comment: I found this bug posting on their forms: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17841#tab=Comments

Comment: So it is related to the EAP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was a bug in PyCharm. Resolved in 5.0.3. 
REF: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/PY-17841

Comment: I had the same problem with Python 3.5.0 + PyCharm 5.0.2, but now it seems fied with 5.0.3. Great!