# How to provide generic type parameter to Sequence[T]?

Tags: python, generics, pycharm, type-hinting

I'm trying to create a list storing elements of type `T` in Python, however, I don't know how to specify the concrete type for an instance of such list.

For non-list instances, the implementation is pretty clear:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T")


class MyGenericType(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.value: T = None


generic_instance: MyGenericType[int] = MyGenericType()
```

The last line just works as expected: It makes `T` instances of `int` and I can store such values in it then.

For lists, I thus wrote the following:

```
from typing import TypeVar, Sequence

T = TypeVar("T")


class MyGenericList(Sequence[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.store: Sequence[T] = []

    # abstract method implementations cut for brevity


generic_list: MyGenericList[int] = MyGenericList()
```

The last line should have created a list storing `int` elements, but my IDE (PyCharm) complains around the first opening square brace:

**Class 'ABCMeta' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances**

Apparently it tried to access the list elements via indexing operator, however, I want to specific the generic type at this place. Is that not possible or am I doing something wrong?

Can it be this is just a PyCharm bug? This does sound similar to [Python 3.5 Typing ABCMeta does not define '__getitem__'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34032272/python-3-5-typing-abcmeta-does-not-define-getitem), but I'm already running the 2017.1.4 version of the IDE, and the bug mentioned in the question only affected hinting on return types (it seems).

Comment: I don't know the meaning of : in "self.value: T = None" syntax. Could someone help me out pointing to some documentation to learn more about it? Sorry to spam - my poor google skills also did not help me with any meaningful search results.

Comment: Have you looked at his checker http://mypy-lang.org/?

Comment: @c0dec0de https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/

Comment: Thanks @AshwiniChaudhary, this seems to be python 3.x specific and I learn that we can have explicit types for variables just like go and many other languages. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I had to inherit from `Generic[T]` for lists aswell. I'm not sure why, I thought `Sequence[T]` would already do that for me. Maybe someone can explain the background on this.

```
class MyGenericList(Generic[T], Sequence[T]):
    def __init__(self):
        self.store: Sequence[T] = []
```

According to the original notes on how generics work, this however seems to be a bug with PyCharm, and the additional derivation from `Generic[T]` should not be required...

Comment: It seems that you have to put `Generic[T]` into ancestors even if some of them inherits it. See `MutableSequence` in `typing.pyi`

Comment: I think this is a PyCharm bug -- I wasn't able to repro this using mypy. There's also a very slight chance that this might partially be due to you using an older version of Python (which comes shipped with an older version of `typing.py`) causing a weird interaction somewhere, but it's hard to say. For context, [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/) used to specify all user-defined types need to subclass `Generic[T]`, but this restriction was later lifted when you subclass other generic types for ergonomic reasons. Perhaps this is where the mixup comes from?

Comment: It wouldn't make much logical sense to me either that I'd have to explicitly derive from `Generic[T]` aswell. PyCharm seems to have a lot of issues at the moment when it comes to (generic) type hints - it just randomly started to complain about the very first hinted member assignment in every `__init__` of _all_ my classes to "get no return" where it expected them to return whatever I hinted for that member.... possibly resorting to JetBrains about this.